# How can I add an additional field to pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter with the value of another field?

Tags: python, python-logging

This is my current json formatter defined in my ini file:

```
[formatter_json]
class=pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter
format=%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s
```

What I want is to add an additional field named `severity` with the same value as `levelname`. Is this possible?

I don't want to remap it I want to add an additional field so I have a `severity` field AND a `levelname` field.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a context filter:

> You can also add contextual information to log output using a
> user-defined `Filter`. `Filter` instances are allowed to modify the
> `LogRecords` passed to them, including adding additional attributes
> which can then be output using a suitable format string, or if needed
> a custom `Formatter`.
>
> [Source in the Python Logging Documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information)

Like this:

```py
import logging
import logging.config

class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        # This adds the "severity" attribute to the record
        # that then can be used by the formatters
        record.severity = record.levelname
        return super().filter(record)

logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf")
logger = logging.getLogger("foobar")
logger.addFilter(ContextFilter())
```

And inside `logging.conf`:

```
[formatter_json]
class=pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter
format=%(asctime)s %(name)s [severity:%(severity)s] %(levelname)s %(message)s
```